# Title case: Which is better ? pre or post-modifier in this case?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, past-participles, modifiers

Followings are titles for a thesis on Ambrogio Lorenzetti’s *Allegory of the Good Government.*
Ambrogio Lorenzetti depicted two Justices in his picture.
Among the four, which one is grammatically best ? Premodifier? or post modifier? visualized or illustrated?
I think (1)or(4) is good. However, I cannot  explain it grammatically, why I think so. Please give me some comments or advice.

1. Why does He depict Two Images of Justice?
   : **Visualised** Aristotle and Thomas Aquinas’ Political Theory in Ambrogio Lorenzetti’s Allegory of the Good Government
2. Why does He depict Two Images of Justice?
   : Aristotle and Thomas Aquinas’ Political Theory **visualised** in Ambrogio Lorenzetti’s Allegory of the Good Government
3. Why does He depict Two Images of Justice?
   : **Illustrated** Aristotle and Thomas Aquinas’ Political Theory in Ambrogio Lorenzetti’s Allegory of the Good Government
4. Why does He depict Two Images of Justice?
   : Aristotle and Thomas Aquinas’ Political Theory **illustrated** in Ambrogio Lorenzetti’s Allegory of the Good Government

Comment: "Illustrated" is for things with illustrations. "Visualized" is for things with any kind of visual aid, typically diagrams, usually used to help explain something.

Comment: @gotube Thank you for your comment. If following your comment, in this case, using 'illustrated ' is better because the thesis is written on a picture?

Comment: The post modifier is far better. I'm indifferent about visualized vs illustrated vs depicted.